# CentOS Server & C#: normal user cannot access to upload an image

Tags: c#, centos, image-uploading, access-denied

I own a server which is currently running CentOS. I can access this server via Putty or Filezilla. 
There are 2 users, root and user1. User1 has no privileges, he has restricted access to a specific folder (I changed its home to this folder, let's call it "userhome") and he owns all the folders inside userhome but he cannot go back to the previous folder in which userhome is contained.
Now the problem is that I need to upload an image in one of these folders using a program I created in C#. The code has been perfectly fine for over three months but now, when it tries to login as user1, the server kinda rejects the request. Since the code has not been modified, it seems reasonable to me that something changed inside the server. I thought that it could be some kind of automatic protection, but I couldn't get anywhere further. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!